# Create independent library, which will use other libraries

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, javacv

I've already asked about some similar things connected with theme above and google a lot, but I still can't find exactly what I want, so here we go:

I want to make library, which will use other libraries. I mean some of javacv's .jar's, which we can find here: [javacv site](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/)
. Some of these libraries are 'normal', some of them contains .dll's. I want to create **independent** .jar file, which could be use together with above .jars in different projects. Classes in this my .jar file will use methods from javacv's .jars. So my 'independent' library will depend on javacv.

In parallel, I'd like to write application, which will use javacv and my library. So I'd like to create 2 projects:

**A) Library, which will depend on javacv 's jar's** (I should get here .jar, which could be use in other projects together with javacv) 
 
**B) Application which will depend on library from A) and javacv's jars**

**What should I do in Netbeans (or eventually in Eclipse) to organize it in best way?** I know, that I probably should use maven / create some maven projects but I don't know a lot about maven ( I can add... dependency :) ).

Comment: Maven, or another build tool, is certainly worth learning. Regardless of the answers you get here, these build tools have this problem solved, so I'd look into them.